# App Registration - User unable to access app even after adding permission, getting error Need Admin Approval

Tags: azure

We have registered our application using App Registration in the Azure Portal. Then try to give Default Access permission to the user by adding user using **Microsoft Entra ID => Enterprise Applications=> All Applications =>  => Users and Group**. But user unable to access the app after successful Azure AD authentication.

User getting below error. Attached error page here. Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Tried giving user default access permission  using **Microsoft Entra ID => Enterprise Applications=> All Applications =>  => Users and Group**. But it is giving error Need Admin Approval after even successful Azure AD Authentication.

Comment: In the app registration (azure.portal) an admin needs to grant consent

Answer (score 2):

> App Registration - User unable to access app even after adding permission, getting error Need Admin Approval

Thanks to `Thomas` for suggesting the same point.

The `Need admin approval` error message usually occurs if the `API permission` has not been granted admin consent

In my case, `Admin Consent` has not been granted to my application's `API permission`, so I also received the same error

**API Permission:**

[image]

[image]

To resolve the issue, grant the `Admin consent` in your application by following the steps below.

***Go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory >Select your application  >  API Permissions > Grant Admin Consent***

[image]

Now, sign in to your application with a `Global Admin` account and accept the consent.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also allow users to consent to the application without `Admin Approval` by navigating.

**Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Application -> User Settings -> Go to Consent and permissions**

[image]